# System.Windows.Forms namespace not recognized in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, namespaces

I've got a service that's acting up. It won't recognize the following namespace declaration:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

What I most need from the Windows.Forms namespace is a WebBrowser control. Any ideas on how to get this working? Thank you.

Comment: And just exactly what do you think you're going to be able to do with a `WebBrowser` in a Windows Service?  You're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: A Windows Service should not present a GUI of any kind whatsoever... because a service can be run without a logged in user, and therefore, won't necessarily even have a desktop!

Comment: I'm trying to parse the HTML of a webpage, I was under the impression this was the best way to do it.

Comment: A service does not start a Windows Forms message pump, so my guess is the web browser component would not work anyway. So, how did it end up ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms in the project.

Here is how you do it: (copied from the user below - thankyou!):

you need to add reference to it's assembly

right click your project node in solutions explorer and

**choose AddReference --> .Net -->System.Windows.Forms**

Just make sure that you don't call MessageBox from your service. It is not a smart thing to do. (Yes, I have blocked services that way)

Comment: Correct answer to the question, but this is totally the wrong thing to do. A Windows service should never interact with the desktop. If the service really needs a UI element, create it as a separate binary that runs in the context of the logged on user, and communicates with the service process.

Answer (score 4):

you need to add reference to it's assembly

right click your project node in solutions explorer and

choose **AddReference** --> **.Net** -->**System.Windows.Forms**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you expect to use a WebBrowser control in a Windows service, a type of application that inherently does not have a user interface.  What you probably need is a reference to the System.Windows.Forms library.   If you right click on your project and go to Add Reference..., there will be a whole list of reference.  Scroll down and select System.Windows.Forms and clikc OK and you should be good to go.